# Different CSS styling for left and right side table data

Tags: css, html-table

This is my table:

```
<table width="100%">
<tr ><td width="35%" height="30" class="left-info" >Criminal Id :</td>
<td width="65%"  class="right-info" >CR7887898652</td></tr>
<tr><td height="30"  class="right-info" >Full Name :</td><td  class="left-info" ></td></tr>
<tr><td height="30"  class="right-info" >Date of Birth :</td><td  class="left-info" ></td></tr>
</table>
```

How can I remove these repeating use of class for each table data. As, I've used  `class="left-info"` for left side table data and  `class="right-info"` for right side table data. But, this make the mesh of coding, can anyone suggest me how can I do the same style with minimal code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either switch to a non-table layout (perhaps a `DL` may suit your needs better), or if you must use a table, consider using the `col` element, which you can apply a `class` attribute to.

### Example

Using your example above, this is how I would suggest using the `col` element.

```
<table id="example">
    <col class="label" />
    <col class="value" />

    <tr>
        <td>Criminal Id :</td>
        <td>CR7887898652</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Full Name:</td>
        <td>Foo Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Date of Birth:</td>
        <td>01/14/1983</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But, taking into account your example, I think you could accomplish your goal with better semantics and less code if you make use of `TH` elements and pure CSS:

```
#example th {
    text-align: right;
    font-weight: normal;
}

#example td {
    text-align: left;
}
```

...

```
<table id="example">
    <tr>
        <th>Criminal Id :</th>
        <td>CR7887898652</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Full Name:</th>
        <td>Foo Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Date of Birth:</th>
        <td>01/14/1983</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

At this level, it shouldn't really matter if you use a `DL` or a `TABLE` as they both are semantically rich elements when used like this. IMHO, I still prefer a `DL`, but truthfully they can be more difficult to style.

Comment: can you me, one example or any link where i can get the reference.

Comment: Yes, `dl` would be a better choice. Looks like non-tabular data to me.

Comment: @sql_query Try Googling 'html dl'.

Comment: `col` element is helpful for me..:)